# Why are the derivatives of these two equations different?

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

I am trying to implicitly differentiate the following: $\frac {x}{x-y}\ =\ y^2-1 $

I originally multiplied the whole equation by $(x - y)$ and the result of implicitly differentiating the resulting equation ($\ x=xy^2-x-y^3+y $ ) was $\frac {dy}{dx}\ = \frac {2-y^2}{2xy-3y^2+1} $ but then afterwards, when I tried again and differentiated the original expression, $\frac {x}{x-y}\ =\ y^2-1 $, (without manipulating it) I ended up with the correct answer of $\frac {-y}{2y(x-y)^2-x} $.

My question is why does simply changing the form of the equation you're trying to implicitly differentiate (like I have done above) change what you get as $\frac {dy}{dx} $ ?

Comment: You lose information by manipulating the equation. In the original, you are guaranteed $x\not=y$. In the manipulated version, this fact is not absolutely certain.

Comment: While what chharvey said is true, 

Note that

$$
 2 - y^2 = 2 - \left( 1 + \frac{x}{x-y} \right) = 1-\frac{x}{x-y} =  \frac{-y}{x-y},
$$

It might be your expressions are equal.

Comment: I've tried to check it (I could be wrong) but I don't think that they equal each other. Should I in future not manipulate an equation if I'm going to implicitly differentiate it to be on the safe side? Or is there a rule of thumb about when it's OK to manipulate and when it's not OK?

Comment: quick rule of thumb:  whenever you multiply or divide by a quantity that could potentially be zero, you need to be careful.  (i.e. you might lose information)

Comment: So for the sake of argument, if it _was_ originally specified in the question that x≠y, which would mean x-y≠0, why would the two derivatives equal different things for some coordinate, say (1,2)? Does the notion that the thing you're multiplying through by doesn't equal 0 still not mean that you won't lost information?

Comment: @chharvey you don't lose information by manipulating the equation. You do have to be careful if you divide by something that may be $0$.

Comment: @SamWeatherhog you absolutely do lose information. Here's another example: given $a=b$, you might decide to square both sides and share the modification. Someone else, receiving $a^2=b^2$ and not having the original equation, might offer $a=2$, $b=-2$ as a solution. This clearly satisfies the modified but does not satisfy the original. Some information from the original equation is lost when squaring both sides.

Comment: @mathphys you can't just pick a random coordinate (e.g. (1,2)) to check whether the derivatives are the same. You need to pick a coordinate that satisfies the original equation.

Comment: @chharvey So just as an example, you cannot square both sides of a simple equation, say $ y = \sqrt{2x+3} $ as this way you _will_ lose information, correct? (because if you did square both sides of this equation, it would now not be known if $ y = + \sqrt{2x+3} $ or $ y = - \sqrt{2x+3} $ ) Note: sorry for so many re-posts, I just keep re-formulating my question!

Comment: mathphys to clear this up, any operation that you perform that is not invertible (i.e. squaring is not invertible, multiplying by $0$ is not invertible) means that you will lose information as you can't recover exactly what you started with. Multiplying by a non-zero quantity is invertible because you can divide by the same quantity to recover the original information. This is what you did to manipulate your original equation. Apologies @chharvey for the confusion caused - you were right, multiplying by $0$ does mean you lose information in the sense that you can't invert the operation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Contrary to what was said in the comments, you lose no information by your manipulation. In the original equation, you knew $x\ne y$. You don't lose anything by multiplying by $x-y$. You have correctly differentiated both expressions, so we have:

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2-y^2}{2xy-3y^2+1}, \text{ and} \\ \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-y}{2y(x-y)^2-x}
$$

We would like to reconcile these two expressions. To do this, we use the equation we started with: $\frac{x}{x-y}=y^2-1$. There are many ways to see that the two expressions are equivalent (on the curve defined by $\frac{x}{x-y}=y^2-1$). One way is to note first that:

$$
\begin{split} \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-y}{2y(x-y)^2-x}=\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{-y}{(x-y)\left(2y(x-y)-\frac{x}{x-y}\right)} \\ &=\frac{\frac{-y}{x-y}}{2y(x-y)-\frac{x}{x-y}} \\ &=\frac{\frac{-y}{x-y}}{2xy-2y^2-\frac{x}{x-y}} \\ &=\frac{\frac{-y}{x-y}}{2xy-2y^2-(y^2-1)}, \text{ since }\frac{x}{x-y}=y^2-1 \\ &= \frac{\frac{-y}{x-y}}{2xy-3y^2+1} \end{split}
$$

As you can see we are almost at the second expression now. The final part has already been done in the comments. I will repeat it here for completeness. Taking the other expression we have:

$$
\begin{split} \frac{2-y^2}{2xy-3y^2+1} &=\frac{2-\frac{2x-y}{x-y}}{2xy-3y^2+1}, \text{ since }y^2=1+\frac{x}{x-y} \\ &=\frac{\frac{2x-2y-2x+y}{x-y}}{2xy-3y^2+1} \\ &=\frac{\frac{-y}{x-y}}{2xy-3y^2+1}\end{split}
$$

which is what we had above. So both expressions are equivalent. In general you can manipulate your equation before you implicitly differentiate. You do need to be careful if you divide by something that may be $0$. Multiplying by $0$ is fine, always.